# "graphic driver: Unknown" when using an ATI Radeon Xpress 200M

Tags: 11.10, ati, radeon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get my graphics card to be recognized in System Info?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85318/how-can-i-get-my-graphics-card-to-be-recognized-in-system-info)

I have just upgraded to Ubuntu 11.10 and although the system seems to work properly, in System Settings > System Info, i'm getting "Graphics Driver: Unknown"

I found some answers about fglrx and ati drivers but what should I choose?
should I do something to fix this?

Comment: So does the open-source drivers mean the card is no better than a VGA card? The open-source driver can't access any of the ATI features?

Comment: @Thinker in short? Yes. You cannot use the fglrx driver under Linux with this card (or you need to use a older kernel to use it), that means you need to use the open-source drivers with it under Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 1):

You cant change that, the last driver that supported your hardware was 2 and half years ago, 9.3 which you cannot run with the current versions of xorg and kernel present in Ubuntu.

You cant install the current fglrx for your card, stick with the drivers open-source drivers present in your system.

```
Radeon (Catalyst Legacy & Open Source)

ATI/AMD dropped Catalyst support for these cards in Catalyst 9-4. These cards are supported with the legacy ATI 9-3 Catalyst release, but you MUST use a kernel 2.6.28 (or earlier) and Xserver 1.5 (or earlier). For example, you can use Catalyst 9-3 if you're running Ubuntu 8.04 or Debian Lenny/5.0. Open source support is good and 3D is still improving.

* RS400/RS480 Radeon XPRESS 200(M)/1100 IGP
```